# creating regex with letters and accents

Tags: php, regex

i need to create a regular expresion that match word whitespace word, it can't start with whitespace neither has more than 1 whitespaces between word and word i have to allow on each word letters and accents, i'm using this pattern:

`^([^\+\*\.\|\(\)\[\]\{\}\?\/\^\s\d\t\n\r<>ºª!@"·#~½%¬&=\'¿¡~´,;:_®¥§¹×£µ€¶«²¢³\$\-\\]+\s{0,1}?)*$/`

**Examples:**

```
-Graça+whitespace+anotherWord            -> match
-whitespace+Graça+whitespace+anotherWord -> don't match
-Graça+whitespace+whitespace+anotherword -> don't match
```

In general, it is a validation to allow firstname+whitespace+lastname with accents chars and a-z chars

and i have to exclude all specials chars like /*-+)(!/($=

Comment: Can you give some examples of strings you would like to match or not match?

Comment: So what are the test inputs that is failing at? Are you just trying to make it simpler?

Comment: Sure, i would like to match something like this:

**Examples:**

1.) Graça somethingelse ->match
2.) (whitespace)Graça somethingelse ->not match

General: firstname+lastname with just one space between those 2 words

Comment: Please Edit your Question with sample inputs.

Comment: Just for the record, none of the characters that you have inside that giant character set actually needs to be escaped, other than `[` and ```\``` (`-` is interpreted literally as long as it appears at the very first or very last character of the set). Also `{0,1}?` can simply be written as `??`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this pattern: `^[\x{0041}-\x{02B3}]+\s[\x{0041}-\x{02B3}]+`.

Explanation: since you are using characters not matched by `\w`, you have to define your own range of word characters. `\x{0041}` is just a character with unicode index equal to `0041`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Ag9Bo/2)

Comment: This regex allows many non-alphabetic characters: [, \, ], ^, _, `, {, |, }, ~, delete (U+007F), control characters (U+0080–U+009F), non-breaking space (U+00A0), £, ½, ¿, ×, ÷, as well as many others. Also, it allows a few of the spacing modifier letters, such as ʰ and ʳ, but not the rest, such as ʴ or ʷ.

Comment: Yeah, i saw that but that comment about define my own range of word characters help me a lot, i finally made it work with this pattern: ^([\x{0041}-\x{005A}\x{0061}-\x{007A}\x{00C0}-\x{00F6}\x{00F8}-\x{024F}]+\s??)*$/u

Answer (score 1):

For just spaces, use **str_replace**:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

For all whitespace, use **preg_replace**:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```